# awk outputting elements out of order

Tags: arrays, bash, csv, awk

In my bash script I am trying to make two parallel arrays with elements in a csv file. The csv file can have anywhere from 5-40 lines in it.

```
Array1=($(awk -F, '{a[$1];}END{for (i in a)print i;}' list.csv))
Array2=($(awk -F, '{b[$2];}END{for (i in b)print i;}' list.csv))
```

After doing this however, the order of the elements in the arrays do not match the file and they do not even match each other. It's like awk is getting lines randomly. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array1=($(awk -F, 'BEGIN{i=0;}{a[i++]=$1;}END{for(x=0;x<i;x++) print a[x];}' list.csv))
Array2=($(awk -F, 'BEGIN{i=0;}{b[i++]=$2;}END{for(x=0;x<i;x++) print b[x];}' list.csv))
```

In awk you have associative arrays, so when you execute the for in it's not sure that you'll get the values in the same order in which you put them inside.
If you want to have them ordered use a counter as index and a normal for loop instead of the for in.

Answer (score 2):

Associative array indices are not kept in order. You are seeing the effects of awk's internal indexing.

Instead, you can add them in the order you want and then print them in that order:

```
Array1=($(awk -F, '!a[$1]++ { b[n++]=$1; } END{for (i=0; i<n; i++) print b[i];}' list.csv))
```

However, you don't even need to store them all up. If you just want the first of each duplicate:

```
Array1=($(awk -F, '!a[$1]++ { print $1; }' list.csv))
```

`!a[$1]++` is a common trick which is true the first time you see the variable (`a[$1]` is considered 0 when unset. `++` increments it for the next time.).

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't need awk for this task: you don't have to read the file twice:

```
array1=()
array2=()
while IFS=, read -r a b; do
    array1+=( "$a" )
    array2+=( "$b" )
done < list.csv
```